# While statement in SQL Cursor bringing null values

Tags: sql, database, database-cursor

I got a table with typical values like: identification, phone number, persons name etc. In this table if a person has more than one phone number that person will appear multiple times, each iteration with a different phone number corresponding to that person.

My goal is to write a cursor that will add all the different phones a person has in a single phone value in a new table, each of them separated by a ', '. In that way each person will only appear once in the table, but the phone numbers value will have al the phone number that person owns separated by a ','.

I have come with something like this:

> Here I create the "normalized" table that persons info should be insert:

```
CREATE TABLE Telefono_General_V2 (Cedula_v2 varchar(50),Nombre_v2 varchar(50),Cantidad int, Telefono_v2 varchar(max))
```

> This is a temporary table to select persons ID that is repeated multiple times, meaning it has multiple phone numbers (Telefonos_General is the table I am getting the data from).

```
SELECT  Cedula_v1 AS Cedula, COUNT(1) AS cantidad_repetidos
INTO #DatosRepetidosTemp
FROM Telefonos_General
GROUP BY Cedula_v1
HAVING  COUNT(1) >1
```

> Here I declare the variables used in the cursor:

```
DECLARE
@Cedula varchar(50),
@Cuenta int,
@Prev_Telefono varchar(max),
@Telefonos varchar(max)
```

> Then declare the cursor itself:

```
DECLARE cursor_telefonos CURSOR FOR 
SELECT TOP (100) Cedula, cantidad_repetidos, Telefono_v1
FROM #DatosRepetidosTemp     
JOIN Telefonos_General on Cedula_v1 = Cedula
WHERE  Cedula is not null
```

> Start the cursor:

```
OPEN cursor_telefonos  
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_telefonos 
INTO @Cedula, @Cuenta, @Prev_Telefono
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN  
    IF @Telefonos = NULL
        SET @Telefonos = @Prev_Telefono
    ELSE
```

> This is the while loop that is returning @Prev_Telefono as null when it should be the (@Telefonos+ ', ' + @Prev_Telefono).

```
    WHILE @Cuenta != 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Telefonos = @Telefonos+ ', ' + @Prev_Telefono
        SET @Prev_Telefono = @Telefonos
        SET @Cuenta = @Cuenta - 1

    END
    INSERT INTO Telefono_General_V2 (Cedula_v2, Cantidad, Telefono_v2)
    VALUES (@Cedula, @Cuenta, @Telefonos)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cursor_telefonos INTO @Cedula, @Cuenta, @Telefonos
```

> Here I just close the cursor:

```
END
CLOSE cursor_telefonos
DEALLOCATE cursor_telefonos
```

Someone knows why my while loop is inserting null on the new phones table when it should be adding a list of phone numbers of that person?

Thanks a lot for your attention!!

Comment: Use `is null` rather than equality. Don't you need to read new values inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct then below can be the possible reason .

**1-** In the code where you are finding the person id having multiple phone number and then getting the different phone numbers for that particular person id after joining it with Telefonos_General. (Here you should short your data on person id although joins will take care of it but please do validate it)

**2-** In the variable declaration code where you are assigning values to Telefonos (please validate the else statement).

**Note--Also for your use case you can use String Aggregate functions which will add all the phone numbers with comma separator. (I had previously use this function for the same use case in Postgress but I am sure you will get it in mssql as well.)**

Assume you have data like below

```
name    date1
 A    2019-03-01
 B    2020-03-01
 A    2021-03-01
 B    2022-03-01
 C    2023-03-01
```

**You can use below query**

```
select name,string_agg(date1,',') as merge_date from table_name group by name
```

**This will give you:**

```
name    merge_date
 A    2019-03-01,2021-03-01
 B    2022-03-01,2020-03-01
 C    2023-03-01
```